# Memory leak in OpenCV function: cvQueryFrame()

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, opencv

I have a problem with `IplImage*` returned from `cvQueryFrame`... Its memory is never released by library. And documentation says:

> The returned image should not be released or modified by the user.

Well... how do I get my memory back? The program eats memory until it crashes. I would like to release allocated memory for each `IplImage*` after frame processing finishes. Code is this:

```
// In `process` thread:
CvCapture* camera;
camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(1);
assert(camera);
while(true)
{
    main = cvQueryFrame(camera);
    // Do something useful with images 
    emit sendImage(main); // Send Image to the UI thread
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This is `QThread` subclass:

```
#include <QThread>
class ImageFetcher : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImageFetcher(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
    void run();
public slots:
};
```

Implementattion:

```
void ImageFetcher::run()
{
    CvCapture* camera = cvCreateCameraCapture(0);
    IplImage* image;
    while(true)
    {
        image = cvQueryFrame(camera);
        // process image
    }
    // exec();
}
```

main():

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc,argv);
    ImageFetcher thread;
    thread.start();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As far as I could test, there's no leak in v2.3.1 for Linux.**

Here is what happens: an image is allocated by `cvQueryFrame()` when this function is called by the first time, and then this image is reused on all subsequent calls to `cvQueryFrame()`. No new images are created after the first call, and the image is only freed at `cvReleaseCapture()`.

So you see, if you are experiencing a memory leak (how did you find it, exactly?) and a crash, it is most probably caused by some other part of your code. If `sendImage()` is not synchronized (i.e. non-blocking) passing `main` image directly could cause problems. I don't know what you are doing in this function, so I'll assume the problem is inside it.

One test you could do, is copy the `main` frame and then pass that copy to `sendImage()` instead, then release it when you no longer need it.

Comment: No, It's absolutely leak of `OpenCV` or `Qt`! I found that this happens only when `cvQueryFrame()` is called in a thread other than main thread. And this happens only with threads of Qt (subclasses of `QThread`),  I tested with `std::thread` there was no problem. Probably it's ok with POSIXs too, (didn't tested). I think it's a leak because when I open a monitor, I can see that memory of program grows fast and unlimitedly. (100 Megabytes per second). if it's important, the crazy growing memory is on heap (as monitor shows). I tried removing `emit sendImage(main)` but didn't help.

Comment: What OpenCV version are you using? You need to make sure `cvCreateCameraCapture()` is only called once during your program execution. If you need to call it more than once, make sure you pair it with the appropriate `cvReleaseCapture()`. If you are unable to fix this issue, I suggest taking a look at [qt-opencv-multithreaded](http://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/) and see how they do it.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132946/parallelize-opencv-processing-with-qt) also may contain some interesting info. Have you considered using [QtConcurrent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtconcurrent.html)? I would like to see a minimal example that reproduces the problem you are observing. =)

Comment: yes, `cvCreateCameraCapture()` is called once and there is one corresponding `cvReleaseCapture()`. I didn't used `QtConcurrent`, will try and tell results. I'll edit post in a couple of minutes...

Comment: Ooops! I did `cvResize(main,anotherImage)` ... It should be a clone of `main`, that could be released by `cvReleaseImage()`. There was no leak, sorry :-)